# Python list dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a few 'list' containing few dictionaries- say 3 dicts.
3 dictionaries as follows:

```
lstone = [{'dc_test': 1}, {'ac_test':2}, {'con_test':3}]
lsttwo = [{'dc_test': 4}, {'ac_test':5}, {'con_test':6}]
```

How do i create new lists as follows:

```
newlistone = ['dc_test',1,4]
newlisttwo = ['ac_test',2,5]
newlistthree = ['con_test',3,6]
```

My objective is to write a new csv file, so that it shows as follows:

```
dc_test,1,4
ac_test,2,5
con_test,3,5
```

Comment: Will the dicts in the original lists always contain exactly one key-value pair?  Will the two lists always contain dicts with identical keys?

Comment: Do you really need the resulting lists to be assigned to separate variables?

Comment: @Wooble: yes, ori dicts is one key-value pair.yes identical, keys too. @Vlad: dont understand, but the orders needs to be maintained in the resulting list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First convert your list to dictionaries

```
d = [dict(itertools.chain(*(d.iteritems() for d in a)))
     for a in [lstone, lsttwo]]
```

Next build the transposed list:

```
keys = d[0].keys()
transposed = [[e[k] for k in keys] for e in d]
```

Finally, transpose and use `csv.writer` to write this to a file:

```
with open("a.csv", "wb") as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(zip(keys, *transposed))
```

Comment: What if not all of the keys are present in `d[0]`?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! Trying to understand step 1 by taking them into parts. Tranposing is the keything in the steps, I guess.

Comment: @siva: transposing isn't that relevant.  I just used it as a convenient way to get the keys in.  You could also use `data = [[k] + [e[k] for e in d] for k in keys]` to get the data in the right orientation right away. (You'd need `.writerows(data)` further down.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the input data can't be represented with 2-tuples instead of dicts?

If the answer is no, then other solutions I've seen so far won't work for all possible cases, like an input item having more than one entry in the dict. This one will:

```
from collections import defaultdict
lstone = [{'dc_test': 1}, {'ac_test':2}, {'con_test':3}]
lsttwo = [{'dc_test': 4}, {'ac_test':5}, {'con_test':6}]

# merge
merge = defaultdict(list)
for e in lstone + lsttwo:
    for k, v in e.items():
        merge[k].append(v)
# flatten
result = [ [k] + v for k, v in merge.items()] 
print result
# your option as to how to convert to CSV
```

Comment: works too!.. what possible cases that other solutions wont work are you referring to? examples?

Comment: One of the inputs could be `[{'dc_test': 1, 'ac_test':2}, {'con_test':3}]`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can create the lists:

```
def makeLists(*lists):
    for dicts in zip(*lists):
        key = dicts[0].iterkeys().next()
        yield [key] + [d[key] for d in dicts]

newlistone, newlisttwo, newlistthree = makeLists(lstone, lsttwo)
```

This code assumes that each list contains the same number of dictionaries, and that corresponding dictionaries contain exactly on entry with the same key.

To write it all to a file use this:

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(",".join(newlistone) + "\n")
    # other lines individually
```

You can also put all lists in one list and loop over them when writing to the file.

Comment: helpful.. but getting an error :: mx, mn = makeLists(max_val, min_val     ValueError: too many values to unpack. My ori list kinda have hundreds of dicts in them.

Comment: @siva: Then just use `myLists = list(makeLists(...))`. Also, this is very basic stuff, maybe you should read the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) first.

Comment: yes, you are right. im starting from scratch and starting to love python. experimenting bits here and there. still in the learning curve. :) only going through the tutorial on need-basis but get stucks sometimes.